# Backtest.js "ReferenceError: list is not defined"

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, referenceerror

Installed Robinbot, a swing-trade bot using Node.js (https://github.com/yura505/robinbot/issues/13)
but keep running into the same issue when trying to run ./backtest.js:

```
    *** BACKTEST today: 2018-07-07 7:39:34 PM
Downloading historical quotes...
Downloading delayed today quotes...
Downloading NASDAQ Composite index...
Downloading recent earnings...
/Users/mac/bot/robinbot/earnings.js:77
                lst.forEach(function(earning) {
                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at Request._callback (/Users/mac/bot/robinbot/earnings.js:77:21)
    at Request.self.callback (/Users/mac/bot/robinbot/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/mac/bot/robinbot/node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/mac/bot/robinbot/node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:272:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1106:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:19)
```

I'm running MacOS High Sierra 10.13.5 and I've updated NPM to the latest version:

```
mac$ node -v
v9.11.1
```

Here is my earnings.js

```
var request = require('request');
var series = require("run-series");

var dates = require('./isodate.js');
var markets = require('./markets.js');
var conf = require('./conf.js');

module.exports = {
    download: function(list, cb) {
        series([function(cb) {
            _list = list.slice();
            download_recent_earnings(cb);
        }, function(cb) {
            download_earnings(cb);
        }], function(err, result) {
            cb();
        });
    },

    getAnnouncement: function(symbol) {
        for (let element of earnings_announcements) {
            if ((element.symbol == symbol) && 
                (dates.diff(dates.today, element.report.date) <= 5) &&
                (new Date(dates.today) < new Date(element.report.date)))
                return { date: element.report.date, timing: element.report.timing };
        }
    },

    isEpsGrow: function(symbol) {
        let reports = earnings_history[symbol];
        let field = "actualEPS";
        return reports[0][field] > reports[1][field] && reports[0][field] > reports[reports.length-1][field];
    },

    soon: function(symbol) {
        let e = this.getAnnouncement(symbol);
        if (e !== undefined) {
           return ((e.date == dates.today && e.timing == "pm") || (e.date == markets.nextDate && e.timing == "am"))
        }
    }
}

var earnings_announcements = [ ];
var earnings_history = { };
var _list;

function download_earnings(cb) {
    if ((global.Robinhood !== undefined) && (conf.earnings_announcements)) {
        let days = dates.diff(dates.today, markets.nextDate) + 1;
        console.log("Downloading earning announcements for "+days+" days...");
        global.Robinhood.earnings({ range: days },
            function(err, resp, body) {
                if (err) return cb(err);
                earnings_announcements = body.results;
                cb();
        });    
    } else cb();
}

function download_recent_earnings(cb) {
    console.log("Downloading recent earnings...");
    let url = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols="+
              _list.slice(0,99).join(',')+"&types=earnings";
    request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return setTimeout(function() {
                download_recent_earnings(list, cb);
            }, 10000);
        }
        let jbody = JSON.parse(body);
        for (let symbol in jbody) {
            let lst = jbody[symbol].earnings.earnings;
            earnings_history[symbol] = lst;
            if (global.backtest) {
                lst.forEach(function(earning) {
                    earnings_announcements.push({
                        symbol: symbol,
                        report : { date: earning.EPSReportDate, timing: "am" }
                    });
                });
            }
            _list.splice(_list.indexOf(symbol), 1);
        }
        if (_list.length > 0)
            return download_recent_earnings(cb);
        cb();
    })
}
```

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?
Much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the relevant contents of `/Users/mac/robinbot/earnings.js`?

Comment: @AlanFriedman Absolutely! https://github.com/yura505/robinbot/blob/master/earnings.js

Comment: You should add it to the question.

Comment: @AlanFriedman Done! Sry!

Comment: I don't see the `list.forEach` mentioned in the error, only `lst.forEach`. Is that a typo? Is this the same code that produced the error?

Comment: @AlanFriedman `lst` is defined, `list` isn't.

Comment: The error points to `list.forEach(function(earning) {`. Where is that in the source?

Comment: @AlanFriedman Hmm strange, I just did a fresh install and now the following error is coming up: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined" pointing to lst.forEach(function(earning) { )

Comment: Can you update the question with the new error?

Comment: @AlanFriedman Updated the question with the new error, and again, thank you for helping me out it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try logging out the value of `jbody[symbol].earnings.earnings;` in each iteration. It may be undefined.

Comment: @AlanFriedman I'm so sorry I'm completely clueless on how to log out the value as of now. I'll do more research on this instead of wasting you're time going back and forth, thank you so much for steering me in a direction!!